# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a classifier in Python but I had a value error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score

input_file = 'income_data.txt'
# Читання даних
X = []
y = []
count_class1 = 0
count_class2 = 0
max_datapoints = 25000
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if count_class1 >= max_datapoints and count_class2 >= max_datapoints:
            break

        if '?' in line:
            continue

        data = line[:-1].split(', ')

        if data[-1] == '<=50K' and count_class1 < max_datapoints:
            X.append(data)
            count_class1 += 1

        if data[-1] == '>50K' and count_class2 < max_datapoints:
            X.append(data)
            count_class2 += 1

# Перетворення на масив numpy
X = np.array(X)

# Перетворення рядкових даних на числові
label_encoder = []
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
for i,item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:, i] = X[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(X[:, i])

X = X_encoded[:, :-1].astype(int)
y = X_encoded[:, -1].astype(int)

# Створення SVМ-класифікатора
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))

# Навчання класифікатора
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Передбачення результату для тестової точки даних
input_data = ['37', 'Private', '215646', 'HS-grad', '9', 'Nevermarried', 'Handlers-cleaners', 'Not-in-family', 'White',
              'Male', '0', '0', '40', 'United-States']
# Кодування тестової точки даних
input_data_encoded = [-1] * len(input_data)
count = 0
for i, item in enumerate(input_data):
    if item.isdigit():
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(input_data[i])
    else:
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(input_data[i]))
        count += 1
input_data_encoded = np.array(input_data_encoded)

# Використання класифікатора для кодованої точки даних
# та виведення результату
predicted_class = classifier.predict(input_data_encoded)
print(label_encoder[-1].inverse_transform(predicted_class)[0])
```

*file with data here https://learn.ztu.edu.ua/pluginfile.php/216720/mod_folder/content/0/income_data.txt?forcedownload=1*

And th error is:

```
 ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lodki\PycharmProjects\Штучний інтелект\lab2\LR_2_task_1.py", line 68, in <module>
    input_data_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(input_data[i]))
  File "C:\Users\lodki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py", line 133, in transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "C:\Users\lodki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1156, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` function of a `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` is expecting an array as an input (as written in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.transform))
but you are giving it `input_data[i]` which is a string.
Either wrap `input_data[i]` into a list or refactor your code to actually transform a list of labels as needed.

As a side not, it is very unclear why you would need to use several LabelEncoders in your code. Your code should identify the data that needs to be encoded, and fit_transform all of it at once using the LabelEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

the sklearn lableEncoder file shows If `y` is not a 1D array or a 2D array with a single row or column, it will Raise ValueError. You can reshape the array using `input_data[i] = np.array(input_data[i]).reshape(1, -1)` or simple add another `[]` to the `input_data[i]`. Do this also to the `input_data_encoded` line.